# React Component not Rendering New Data from Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

This issue comes into play because my high-level components are called before I obtain my initial state via a websocket in the form of a redux store. Therefore when the state is processed by my components they receive only the default state which is an empty Immutable Map(). However, at some point I receive the store from the server, I call setState from my action_creators and that is processed by my reducer which merges the store into my local store. This entire process is logged using redux-logger. See the associated screenshot. You can see that the local state has changed but the components are not rerendered.

[Redux-logger output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0woEg.png)
<- Component State is what the high-level component receives.

I know my actions and reducers work to some degree because if I merge a local JSON file with my local store the state the component receives is not just an empty Map but contains the full state data. However, this does not mean re-rendering works and I am under the assumption that the state has only been process because it was available before the components were initially called.

Please take a look at my index.js, action_creators.js, reducer.js, and my high-level component Game

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {setState} from './action_creators';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import routes from './routes.js';
import reducer from './reducer';
import InitialState from './initial.json';
import './index.scss';

const socket = io(`${location.protocol}//${location.hostname}:8090`);
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(logger)
);

socket.on('state', state => store.dispatch(setState(state)));
// socket.on('state', state => console.log("From Store", store.getState()));
// socket.on('state',store.dispatch(setState(InitialState)));
// console.log("From JSON",InitialState);

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    {routes}
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

reducer.js

```
import {Map} from 'immutable';

export default function(state = Map(), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_STATE':
      return state.merge(state, action.state);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

action_creators.js

```
export function setState(state) {
  return {type: 'SET_STATE',state};
}

export function modIndicator(state, playerId, indicator, modifier) {
  return {type: 'INDICATORS', playerId: playerId, indicator: indicator, modifier: modifier};
}
export function modCollection(state, collection, property, value, op, category) {
  return {
    type:'COLLECTIONS',
    collection:collection,
    property:property,
    value:value,
    op:op,
    category:category};
}
```

Game.js

```
import React, {PureComponent, PropTypes} from 'react';
// import Card from '../../Components/Card/index.js';
// import Collection from '../../Components/Collection/index.js';
import Indicator from '../../Components/Indicator/index.js';
import Counter from '../../Components/Counter/index.js';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actionCreators from './../../action_creators.js';
import './styles.scss';

export default class Game extends PureComponent {
  render() {
let playersById = this.props.playersById;
let collections = this.props.collections;
let counters = this.props.counters;

let indic_list = [];
let coll_list = [];

//Indicators
playersById.forEach(function(value, key, map){
  indic_list.push(<p className="section-name">{playersById.get(key).get('name')+"'s Indicators"}</p>)
  playersById.get(key).get('indicators').forEach(function(value, key, map){
      indic_list.push(<Indicator label={key}>{value}</Indicator>)
  });
});

//Collections
collections.forEach(function(value, key, map) {
  coll_list.push(<span>{key}: {collections.get(key).get("content").size}</span>);
  collections.get(key).get("control").forEach(function(value, key, map){
      coll_list.push(<span>Control: {value}</span>);
  });
});

return (
    <div className="frame">
      <div className="left-col">
        {indic_list}
      </div>
      <div className="center-col">
        <span className="collections">
          {coll_list}
        </span>
      </div>
      <div className="right-col">
        <div className="counters">
          {counters.map(function(type){
            return <Counter label={type}></Counter>
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
  }
}

Game.PropTypes = {
  playersById:  PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  collections: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  counters: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log("Component State",state);
  return {
    playersById: state.get('playersById'),
    collections: state.get('collections'),
    counters: state.get('counters')
  };
}
export const GameContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(Game);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options ahead of you:

#### 1. Set an initial state that your component can use

```
import {fromJS} from 'immutable';

const initialState = fromJS({
    playersById: [],
    collections: [],
    counters: []
});

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_STATE':
      return state.merge(state, action.state);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

#### 2. Provide some suitable data if the data is missing

```
import {List} from 'immutable';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log("Component State",state);
  return {
    playersById: state.get('playersById') || new List(),
    collections: state.get('collections') || new List(),
    counters: state.get('counters') || new List()
  };
}
```

This might be safer as your state gets completely replaced every time, so this will protect your component if the incoming data is not suitable for rendering

#### 3. Make the component handle the missing data

```
render() {

if (!(playersById && collections && counters)) {
    return null; // or a loading spinner?
}

// ... the rest of your render function

}
```

Comment: I ended up doing the second option. It prevented me from having an error from the forEach loop operating on an undefined prop. The Component still initially receives an empty map. After the action is performed the component state receives the entire new state and therefore re-renders everything.